# how restarting game on pygame works

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop, pygame

how can I restart the game with user input? i searched all over the place and i wasnt able to discover how i can restart my game, i just want to press **ESC** and my game restart, after knowing how to do that i will implement a button, but how can I restart my game? this is my main loop:

```py
while True:
    
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    #input
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            #snake
            if event.key == ord('w'):
                change_to = 'UP'
            if event.key == ord('s'):
                change_to = 'DOWN'
            if event.key == ord('a'):
                change_to = 'LEFT'
            if event.key == ord('d'):
                change_to = 'RIGHT'   
                    
            #snake2
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                change2_to = 'UP'
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                change2_to = 'DOWN'
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                change2_to = 'LEFT'
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                change2_to = 'RIGHT'

            #quit game
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                #here is where was supposed to restart the game
```

i cut the major part to not be so long but i dont know how to restart my game

Comment: You can put your entire game main-section into a function, e.g. `runGame()`, and then exit & recall that function.  But it's important to re-initialise everything back to starting state.  There's not enough code in the question to make an accurate answer in this respect.

Comment: yes i did that and put my while True: on a function, but when i runned the program it did nothing, where i call this function for that to work?

Comment: There is presumably some initializing code above your current first `while True` line. Put that entire stuff, including this game loop, into a function and let only the Esc key return from it. Then call that function in a loop. Remember that you can also use that `return` with a value to indicate things like "won", "lost", "restart", and "quit".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should be something like this

```
# imports
restart = False
while running:
    if restart:
        # create instance of all objects used
        # score = 0
        # Default values should be initialised
    # Keyboard events go here
    # code for restarting
    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
        restart = True
```